# a calculator in functions

Tags: c, function, switch-statement, case, calculator

I am trying to write a calculator using functions for each operation and switch case in c language but output is as follows: for example when i enter 5 and 6, and choose addition it prints sss5.000000 +
6.000000 = 11.000000 how can i remove the sss before 5.000000 and what causes this problem? thanks for helping.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float addTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2);
float subtTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2);
float divideTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2);
float multTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2);
float powerTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2);

int main() {

  float num1, num2,add,subt,div,mult,pow;
  int choice;
 
  printf("choose one operation:\n 1.addition\n 2.substraction\n 
  3.division\n 4.multiplication\n 5.power\n");
  scanf("%d" ,&choice);
  printf("Enter two numbers: ");
  scanf("%f %f" ,&num1,&num2);
  add=addTwoNumbers(num1, num2);
  subt=subtTwoNumbers(num1, num2);
  div=divideTwoNumbers(num1, num2);
  mult=multTwoNumbers(num1, num2);
  pow=powerTwoNumbers(num1, num2);
  
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
    
    printf("%f + %f = %f" ,num1,num2);
      break;
    case 2:
    
    printf("%f - %f = %f" ,num1,num2);
      break;
    case 3:
    
     printf("%f / %f = %f" ,num1,num2);
      break;
    case 4:
     
       printf("%f * %f = %f" ,num1,num2);
    case 5:
     
       printf("%f ? %f = %f" ,num1,num2);
      break;
     
    default:
      printf("Error!");
    
  }

    
  return 0;
}

float addTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2)
{
        return float;
        
}
float subtTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2)
{
        float result2;
        result2 = num1-num2;
        return result2;
}
float divideTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2)
{
        printf("s");
}
float multTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2)
{
        printf("s");
}
float powerTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2)
{
        printf("s");
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `%d` in some `printf` statements? That's for integers. Use `%f` for `float`.

Comment: Look closely at this line: `scanf("%f %f" ,&num1,num2);`  One param has a `&`, the other does not.

Comment: sorry i forgot to change them but when i use %f in all of them, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @DilaraA Show the *most correct* code that you have that is not working. Not some stale version which you know have bugs.

Comment: Best to not re-use `pow` as a variable as `pow()` is a `<math.h>` function.  Use another name.

Comment: Why are you performing the calculations twice? Firs you are pre-calculating all possible results, but then, after the choice is made you are calculating the result again

Comment: Minor about naming.. Your functions are all ending with "TwoNumbers", rendering it uninformative, as it does not differentiate it from anything else (like ThreeNumbers or such)

Comment: You made large destructive edits to your original post.  I restored the content you removed.

Comment: You literally call 3 methods that do just that - printf("s"). I vote this question to be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the variables you want `scanf()` to populate (`num2` should be `&num2`).  Check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise your values may be undefined.  The other major problem that your `printf()` format strings "%d" doesn't match your arguments float arguments.  Added a newline, too. Finally, you call all functions before the switch instead of just the you need in the switch.  Implemented your dummy functions.  Moved `main()` to the bottom so you don't need the prototypes of functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float addTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

float subtTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}

float divideTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2) {
    if(num2 == 0) {
       printf("divide by 0!\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    return num1 / num2;
}

float multTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
}

float powerTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2) {
    return powf(num1, num2);
}

int main() {
    printf("choose one operation:\n 1.addition\n 2.substraction\n 3.division\n 4.multiplication\n 5.power\n");
    int choice;
    if(scanf("%d", &choice) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    float num1, num2;
    if(scanf("%f %f", &num1, &num2) != 2) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("%f + %f = %f\n" ,
                num1,
                num2,
                addTwoNumbers(num1, num2)
            );
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("%f - %f = %f\n" ,
                num1,
                num2,
               subtTwoNumbers(num1, num2)
            );
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("%f / %f = %f\n",
                num1,
                num2,
                divideTwoNumbers(num1, num2)
            );
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("%f * %f = %f\n" ,
                 num1,
                 num2,
                 multTwoNumbers(num1, num2)
            );
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("%f^%f = %f\n" ,
                num1,
                num2,
                powerTwoNumbers(num1, num2)
            );
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error!");
    }
}
```

example run:

```
choose one operation:
 1.addition
 2.substraction
 3.division
 4.multiplication
 5.power
1 
Enter two numbers: 1.2 2.3
1.200000 + 2.300000 = 3.500000
```

@abelenky showed you how to refactor it further.  Using tables like that is a powerful technique and I use it often.  Another idea, and mainly to show you something different, is to observe that the only difference between the 4 cases is the operator and the last case it's the same expect you apply a `powf()` function.  SO let's write a `print()` function instead, and optionally define a couple of macros `OP()` and `OP_FUNC()` that applies the operator or function and does the break.  I like how the macros highlight what changes, but others will dislike the that the variables and `break` are hidden.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void print(float num1, const char *op, float num2, float result) {
    printf("%f %s %f = %f\n", num1, op, num2, result);
}

int main() {
    printf("choose one operation:\n 1.addition\n 2.substraction\n 3.division\n 4.multiplication\n 5.power\n");
    int choice;
    if(scanf("%d" ,&choice) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    float num1, num2;
    if(scanf("%f %f" ,&num1, &num2) != 2) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

#define OP(O) print(num1, #O, num2, num1 O num2);\
    break

#define OP_FUNC(O, F) print(num1, #O, num2, F(num1, num2));\
    break

    switch (choice) {
        case 1: OP(+);
        case 2: OP(-);
        case 3: if(num2 != 0) OP(/); else printf("divide by 0\n");
        case 4: OP(*);
        case 5: OP_FUNC(^, powf);
        default: printf("Error!");
    }

#undef OP
#undef OP_FUNC

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much shorter and simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float addTwoNumbers   (float num1, float num2) { return num1+num2;       }
float subtTwoNumbers  (float num1, float num2) { return num1-num2;       }
float divideTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2) { return num1/num2;       }
float multTwoNumbers  (float num1, float num2) { return num1*num2;       }
float powerTwoNumbers (float num1, float num2) { return powf(num1,num2); }

float(*operation_map[])(float,float) =
{
     addTwoNumbers,
     subtTwoNumbers,
     divideTwoNumbers,
     multTwoNumbers,
     powerTwoNumbers
};

char choice_map[]= { '+', '-', '/', '*', '^' };

int main() {

    int choice;
    printf("choose one operation:\n"
           " 1.addition\n"
           " 2.substraction\n"
           " 3.division\n"
           " 4.multiplication\n"
           " 5.power\n");
    scanf("%d" ,&choice);
    
    printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    float num1, num2;
    scanf("%f %f" ,&num1, &num2);
    
    float result = operation_map[choice-1](num1, num2);
    printf("%.2f %c %.2f = %.2f", num1, choice_map[choice-1], num2, result);

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
choose one operation:  1
 1.addition
 2.substraction
 3.division
 4.multiplication
 5.power
Enter two numbers: 3.14 2.71

3.14 + 2.71 = 5.85
```

Comment: I suggest you validate choice as <= 0 or >=6 leads to out of bounds access.  Maybe check for the divide by 0, too?  Upvoted your answer.

Comment: Those are good suggestions. Thx.